# Update shopping cart when change spinner value

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, spinner

I have a shopping cart, in my application is a Datatable. I have a spinner to show the number of that product, and I want that when spinner value changes, refresh my shopping cart, this is my code:

```
<p:dataTable var="carro" value="#{productoBean.productos}">
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Carrito de la Compra" />
  </f:facet>
  <p:column headerText="Producto">
    <h:outputText value="#{carro.producto.nombre}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Cantidad">
    <p:spinner value="#{carro.cantidad}">
      <p:ajax listener="#{productoBean.refreshCantidad}" update="@this" />
    </p:spinner>
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Precio/Unidad">
    <h:outputText value="#{carro.producto.precioUnidad} €" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Valor">
    <h:outputText value="#{carro.valor} €" />
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

I don't know how get the item which spinner change and update its values.

Please I need help, Thanks in advance.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did:

```
<p:column headerText="Cantidad">
  <p:spinner value="#{carro.cantidad}" valueChangeListener="#{productoBean.updateCantidad}">
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{productoBean.refreshCantidad(carro)}" update=":formCarrito" />
  </p:spinner>
</p:column>
```

In `productoBean.updateCantidad` I have:

```
public void updateCantidad(ValueChangeEvent event) {
  cantidad = (Integer) event.getNewValue();
}
```

And in `productoBean.refreshCantidad(carro)` as can be seen, `carro` is the param of the method:

```
public void refreshCantidad(Compra compra) {
  carritoBean.addProduct(compra.getProducto(), cantidad);
}
```

This way I know what's the last value of the spinner and I can update my shopping cart.

Greetings.